# Is there a command to close a terminal window via commandline?

Tags: command-line

Is there a command to close a terminal window via commandline?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To close a terminal window you can use the `exit` command . Alternatively you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to close a terminal tab and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to close the entire terminal including all tabs.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `^D` shortcut - that is, hitting *Control* and *d*. This works in many shells and shell-like environments. Technically speaking, this key combination emits the *end-of-transmission* character (ASCII code 04). In `gnome-terminal`, i.e. `bash` and other shells, this is interpreted as finishing the interactive session. You can also see this behavior in programs like `cat` which read from *standard input* (the keyboard). Try running it without arguments; you can terminate by entering `^D`.

Comment: I like this shortcut!

Answer (score 18):

```
exit
```

is the command you want to use for that.

Answer (score 11):

There is an alternate way, which requires a bit more keystrokes, but is worth knowing.

**Using `exec` command**

- Syntax

```
exec <command-name>
```

- This will first execute the `<command-name>` and then exit the shell.
- For example, you could do:

```
exec sleep 1
```

which would, effectively, close the window after 1 second.

Comment: It doesn't quite "exit" the shell, but it rather replaces the shell's process with the `<command-name>`. When command terminates, process exits.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Running python scripts with bash and killing them later

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is a little bit late but, If you are using Ubuntu or another Linux distro, simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close the entire terminal.

I initially tried all the rest and they were just not working. For example I see people recommending `exit` but honestly, it just doesnt work.

I hope someone agrees with me.

Comment: Ctrl + D works indeed, but in my case "exit" has always been working too... It's weird that it doesn't for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xdotool`:

`xdotool getactivewindow windowkill`

Notice that this will kill all active windows!

If you want to kill only the current window use:

`xdotool key --clearmodifiers Ctrl+Shift+Q key --clearmodifiers KP_Enter`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. A good answer that can be improved. "Try using" is the hallmark of a suggestion and suggestions should go in comments. Replacing it with "You can use" makes it into a proper answer. I'll suggest an editing.

Comment: CelticWarrior Tnx!!!

Comment: That's the command I was looking for! Billion thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.First type `echo $$` in terminal to know it's process id. Then type `kill -9 processid`.

Answer (score 1):

To close the terminal whilst leaving all running processes to continue running, you can do the following:

- pause the process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> , pull it into the background with `bg` and then disown it, eg:

`vlc`

`^Z`

[1]+  Stopped

```
bg
```

[1]+ vlc &
    disown

```
exit
```

This will leave the current running process running in the background and close the terminal(i find this to be very useful).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The command is **exit**. Type **exit** into the terminal and press enter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using KDE here. I wrote a script and I execute it by *right click > execute in console*. After the executtion, the newly opened window of konsole, **was left open** and I had to **manualy close it** (by pressing X or Alt+F4, or typing exit).
I combined two of your answers here (THANKS to the posters) and now the window closes automatically.

Sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
echo Hello & disown
sleep 1
echo Closing in 3
sleep 1
echo Closing in 2
sleep 1
echo Closing in 1
sleep 1
xdotool getactivewindow windowkill
```

Without the *& disown* and *xdotool getactivewindow windowkill*, just by using "exit" at the end, nothing happened!
Thank you again!

Comment: I noticed that while the above script is counting down, if I activate another window, par example, dolphin file manager, then the activated window will close, instead of konsole's window!